# Where's the best place to ask questions about Atmel AVR software (with FreeRTOS)?

Tags: discussion

I am new to Ateml (AVR) - new to embedded programming. I just looked at http://forum.atmel.com/ and they seem to have only two forums: "Touch Technology" and "CryptoMemory".

Maybe I missed something, but I have a shed-load of questions and none of them fit into either of those two categories.

Where's the best place to ask and get answers? Here? http://stackoverflow.com ? Somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Atmel uCs, but a very popular place seems to be [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=index).
The PICList Russell mentions is a truly excellent resource - it does have an AVR tag, as well as PIC/EE/TECH/OT, etc.

Comment: Wow, the tutorials form alone covers everything I can currently think of and answers all of my questions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good place to ask questions in relation to this. I am not sure why every suggests you go to a different site, but we have been slowly growing in all of our subject areas and firmware has always been a goal.

Answer (score 0):

**An** excellent place, but not THE place would be [PICList](http://www.piclist.com) which, despite the name, has a disparate crowd of technical people with a very wide experience base. It's an email based system. Approach is much more informal than in some forums - multiple subject areas you can subscribe to as desired. You have to join (instructions on that page) but you don't get spammed and can leave any time you like. Consider it complementary to membership here and elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I am going to have to award the anser to Oli, but it's is a close run thing and I thank you very much for a great resource

Comment: Mawg - no problem. Oli and I are both on PICList fwiw.

Comment: I hoped you would comment, so that I could award you +1  ;-)